# Adding http request backend java

Tags: java, rest

I'm a beginner in web services and I have a design problem in order to have an efficient code. I have for exemple in my backend a resource like that :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity getAppList() {

    try {

        Assert.notNull(applicationService, "applicationService is null");
        System.out.println("getAppList()");
        List<AppTransferData> list = applicationService.getApplicationList();
        System.out.println(list);
        Assert.notNull(list, "list is null");
        Collections.sort(list);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);            
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    /* adding HTTP Get request here?? */
}
```

I want to add on this resource a http GET request on an other URL domain. Something like that

```
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
...
```

I put this after the catch or not?

Thank you so much

Comment: If the information you get from the external url has to be shown to the user you have to put it before the catch

Comment: The code inside the catch gets executed only if there is an exception in the code above, meaning that something went wrong and the execution cannot continue